# Modern navy ranks, roles and responsibilities

Tags: military, naval

Note: As there is no military related StackExchange, it has been suggested to ask here.

In a modern navy, a carrier can have several thousand crew members. For such a large number of crew, there would obviously be many roles and responsibilities required. Is there a resource that can outline these roles for modern navies?

So far, the most useful resource I have come across is [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Warrantchart.png). However, while it's useful for showing hierarchy and providing a basic understanding of which ranks would fill which roles, the information is for a 19th century navy.

So what I am curious about is firstly what are all the available roles aboard a modern naval carrier (anything from Captain to cook). Which roles would come with an official title, and which roles are not? With thousands of crew, what percentage make up the different roles (and for example, what would be the most common role)?

What are the typical roles of each rank, from seaman to chief petty officer under the enlisted crew, and then the roles that commissioned officers would have?

Several military ranks and shipboard titles coincide. For example the Captain or the First Lieutenant of a ship many have a rank that is higher or lower than the military rank of Captain or Lieutenant. Is there a full list of ship titles outlining their responsibilities? What military ranks would be typical for these titles? How does one distinguish between the two terminologies in a working environment? Would crew be addressed by rank, or title on board?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this unrelated to history.

Comment: Do you know where might be a more appropriate place to ask? I was referred here from another SE site.

Comment: How about Workplace SE since you're asking about the modern military and that is a workplace.

Comment: Sounds good. Is there a way to move this question over?

Comment: The mods can migrate it but cut & pasting the question yourself will be quicker.

Comment: I doubt this is on-topic in workplace, either. Simply put, there is not a stackplace for everything and there seem not to be any about the military right now (although maybe it could be a good idea).

Comment: A captain in the Navy is equivalent to colonel in the army/air force/marines and a lieutenant is equivalent to captain in the land forces so the navy's captain and lieutenant would have way more responsibilities than the others' captain or lieutenant. Also, there is only "Lieutenant" for the navy, there is no 1Lt or 2Lt. There is, however, a "Lieutenant Junior Grade".

Comment: @SJuan76 There is [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria) on Area51.

Comment: [This](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/article/art20130702112133708) applies to UK forces, might help.

Comment: I spent 25+ years in the Navy.  What you are asking is about a book length topic.  I would suggest heading over to any of the web sites (USS Nimitz for example) and browsing through the topics on that site to give an idea about the structure.  Beyond that, you need to narrow down your question to just what it is in that pile of questions at the end that you really want to get an answer to.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Funnily enough, the majority of my limited knowledge on the matter came from pages describing the Nimitz. I've got a basic understanding of the major departments (admin, air wing, deck, etc), but you're definitely right about how much information there is. It's just a matter of piecing it all together from different sites, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

This site details the hierarchy of a modern (WWII) battleship:

[Seamanship](https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USN/ref/Seamanship/Seamanship-7.html)

It seems to be lacking as to the relationship between in-ship responsibilities and military rank. I fear that this is more or less unavoidable unless we discuss each kind of ship separately, though: the commander of a destroyer or submarine would be probably be the Navy equivalent of an Army captain, whereas the commander of a battleship or carrier will probably be something closer to a colonel - and such quite certainly reflects on all official positions on board.